# Why isn't label appearing in fullscreen mode?

Tags: swift, macos, fullscreen

I have this code

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit


class MainScreenVC: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textTest: NSTextField!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //let presOptions :NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [.fullScreen, .autoHideMenuBar]
    //let optionsDictionary = [NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: presOptions]
    //view.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.main!, withOptions: optionsDictionary)

         textTest.stringValue = "Hello"

    }
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {

        }
    }

}
```

textTest has constraints to show it in the middle of the container.

When run, the app displays "Hello" in the middle of a window, as expected.

If I uncomment the lines required to enter fullscreen mode and run the app, it enters full screen, But no text is displayed.

Why?

I am using xCode 10.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I had the same issues, I had come up with 2 solutions, you can either use [toggleFullScreen(*:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419527-togglefullscreen#) or [setFrame(:display:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419753-setframe#) in the **windowController** windowDidLoad function

e.g.:

```
  override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()

    guard let window = window,
      let screen = window.screen
      else { return }


    window.setFrame(window.frameRect(forContentRect: screen.frame), display: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips XueYe. I played around with these and wonder how long ago you used them. Trying toggleFullScreen(:) in Xcode 10.1 generate a complier error 'unresolved identifier 'toggleFullScreen', same with setFrame(:display:). Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited my answer, the key is to put code in the view's window controller to control the window, but not the view.